# Include Blog on my website

Tags: yii, include, comments, blogs

I am building a website, which should also include some blog posts. I am tired of programming and I would like to use some ready solution. What is the best way to include a blog on my website? I would like to keep header and footer and display articles in content wrapper. I also would like to allow logged users to comment articles (what I see now as a problem).

I am using Yii framework and I was thinking, if there is any function like renderPartial which works for websites and not only for views.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use WordPress and integrate it under Yii, this article is pretty good:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/322/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-still-another-approach-using-yii-as-the-router-controller/

(Of course, this is a bit more coding, but WordPress is the best blog software out there, so I think it's worth it!)